# Url rewrite with regular expression not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `RewriteRule` code on my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/demo/>
    # New URL Structure
    RewriteEngine On
    Allow From All
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule "^page/(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$" detail.php?url=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

I have this URL: `http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2` and RewriteRule is working perfect but when I try with this URL `http://example.com/page/parameter-1` it is not working.

```
http://example.com/page/parameter-1 [Not working]
http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2 [Working]
http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2/parameter-3 [Working]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of your regex pattern which is always assuming there is a `/` always after `page/`.

You can simplify this to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/demo/>
    # New URL Structure
    RewriteEngine On
    Allow From All
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^/?page/([a-z].*)$ detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

</Directory>
```

Comment: What If I don't want to allow number on first parameter. Not want to allow 1245: `http://example.com/page/1245/parameter-1` and allow: `http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2`

Comment: In that case use: `RewriteRule ^/?page/([a-zA-Z]+-\d+.*)$ detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: I have tried with `RewriteRule "^/?page/([a-zA-Z]+-\d+.*)$" detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` but this url not working
`http://example.com/page/parameter-1 OR
http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2 OR
http://example.com/page/parameter-1/parameter-2/parameter-3`

Comment: My suggested rules works fine for `http://localhost/page/parameter-1/parameter-2` or `http://localhost/page/parameter-1/parameter-2/param-3` on my apache. Do you have other rules as well?

Comment: Now I got it. Can you check this url: http://example.com/page/one-1/two-2 Will work but http://example.com/page/one/two not work.

Comment: ok try this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?page/([a-z].*)$ detail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Yes its working but after changing rule `http://example.com/page/1245/parameter-1` not work.

Comment: Yes because you wrote this requirement: **What If I don't want to allow number on first parameter**

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets break down what your regex matches:

`^page/` - Your URL must start with "page/", all good so far.

`(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*` - Your URL can have 0 or more segments in it.

`[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$` - Your URL must end with some segment, followed by a slash, followed by anything

This last part is where the regex goes a bit wrong. Your first example does not have a slash after "page/".